# How to resolve the error "object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable"

Tags: r

Here is the procedure:

1. Read the multiple data sets
2. Generate missing samples
3. Then save those.

There was no problem to read the data sets. However, when simulating missing samples, I got an error:

> c[, i] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable

Code:

```
dir=c("C:/")
file=list.files(dir)
file_cnt=length(file)
for (i in 1:file_cnt) {assign(paste0("c", i), read.table(paste(dir, "/", file[i], sep=""), header=T, sep="", dec="."))

mypatterns=c[, i]$mypatterns ### HERE!!!!!!
mypatterns=rbind(mypatterns, c(1,1,0))}

c1[i]=ampute(c[i], prop=.2, patterns=mypatterns, freq=NULL,
             mech="MAR", weights=NULL, run=T)$amp }
```

Comment: if mypatterns is a dataframe, you can use either `$`, or `[]`, but not both: `mypatterns$colname` or `mypatterns[, 'colname']`

Comment: Thank you for your info. I seemed to fix the problem. One more thing is that I need to simulate multiple missing samples with "ampute". Any ideas? (e.g., multiple sets= ampute(multipe... sets) Use another loop? or lapply?